# keyboard shortcut to force dock to appear

Tags: release-loki, plank, keyboard-shortcuts

Loki 0.4 64-bit. Is it possible to assign a keyboard shortcut to force the dock to appear even when a focused window overlaps it?

Comment: Isn't your dock always in front of a focused window? Can you explain more of what you mean?

Comment: No, it isn't. It can be set to hide when any window appears over it. So it would be super helpful to make it appear using a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Here's a scenario. Launch Chrome, maximize window. No dock in sight. Wouldn't it be nice to press a (default or user-assigned) key to make the dock appear and launch an additional application without having to reach for the mouse?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately no. However, if necessary you can make a request for this feature at https://launchpad.net/elementaryos . Otherwise, you can follow these steps to (kind of) peek at the dock:

1. Hold down control and right click the dock at the same time.
2. Select preferences.
3. When the window appears, select the "Behaviour" category.
4. In the drop down, select "Dodge active window" (if it isn't already turned on. If it is, please ignore steps 1-5).
5. Close this window.
6. Now, you can push Super + Space (Super is the windows key on PC's and the command (⌘) key on a Mac) to show the applications menu which will also reveal the dock.

Screenshot:

Push Super + Space and you have visibility to the dock! (push Super + Space again to close the menu and hide the dock
[image: The dock and the app menu]

Answer (score 0):

After I push 'Super + Space' I have to click twice on an app icon in the dock. After first click Applications Menu closes and second click runs whatever I click in the dock.
In gnome I can just bounce mouse cursor of the edge to show dock/favorites menu.
Or maybe if I could configure one of the hot corners to open dock, or if I had any other way to bring up dock fast when app in focus is maximized.
I mean 'Alt + Tab' switches between apps so slow (comparing to gnome).
BTW I love using elementary os.

Just noticed that when you disable dock hiding and maximize your window it will not go behind the dock. It looks bad.

OK just realized I can bounce mouse cursor of the bottom edge and it will show the dock. I take all that back and love elementary os even more!

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to manipulate the way the dock appears or doesn't appear, modifications to it's behavior can be accomplished via Elementary Tweaks. Though I don't believe they can be tied to keyboard shortcuts.